# compatibility of mediaelement.js on BlackBerry and Nokia

Tags: mediaelement.js

I tested mediaelement.js and it works great on iOS 4.0, 5.0 (iPhone 3GS/iPhone 4.0/iPad 1) and on Android 2.0 ,3.0(HTC / Samsung Galaxy Tab ).

What about the compatibility on Windows Phone 7? On http://mediaelementjs.com/, it says "native". What does it mean?

And what about the compatibility on BlackBerry OS and Nokia (Symbian)?

Thanks in advance for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as I can tell it works fine on Windows phone. If you want you can download the Windows phone emulator from Microsoft : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570

Comment: Thanks! It tried today on Windows Phone and it seems to work (I can play a video) but I can't receive any playback events of the video tag (e.g. mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', ...)